# JAXB unmarshal has always null value for nested object

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a web-service, defined by writing its WSDL and underlaying XSD, and the java server code classes / java bindings were generated using JAXB/xjc.

Everything looks fine service is running properly... but for every request (looking well-formed after receiving when looking on log-output) the nested elements seem to be always null when accessing through my java code.

Can someone figure out why customerId.getCustomer() always returns null?

### My XSD (partly):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:tip="http://example.org/tip" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://example.org/tip/pro">

<complexType name="id">
  <attribute name="id" type="int" use="required"/>
  <attribute name="name" type="string" use="optional"/>
</complexType>

<complexType name="customer_id">
  <sequence>
    <element name="customer" type="tip:id" minOccurs="0"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>

<element name="get_customer_request" type="tip:customer_id"/>

</schema>
```

### The generated class CustomerId:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "customer_id", propOrder = {"customer"})
public class CustomerId {
  protected Id customer;

  public Id getCustomer() {
    return customer;
  }

  public void setCustomer(Id value) {
    this.customer = value;
  }
}
```

The generated class for Id look similar, I don't think there is something special.
In my request handler I got the following extract:

### Handler:

```java
JAXBElement<?> request = requestHandler.unmarshallRequest(inputStream);
Object jaxbClass = request.getDeclaredType();
expectedClass = CustomerId.class;
// next line does not throw exception with given XML
if (jaxbClass != expectedClass) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

CustomerId customerId = (CustomerId)request.getValue();
if (customerId == null) {
  logInfo("customerId: null");
} else if (customerId.getCustomer() == null) {
  // this is the part that always will be executed... why?
  logInfo("customerId.customer: null");
} else {
  logInfo("customer id: " + customerId.getCustomer().getId());
  // return mbean.getCustomer(customerId);
}
```

### And finally an example request XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<m:get_customer_request xmlns:m="http://example.org/tip/pro">
  <customer id="0" name="help"/>
</m:get_customer_request>
```

I stripped out SOAP envelope and body tags, since this is not causing any trouble.
Can anyone see, what I am doing wrong? (I am pretty sure, I do...)
Thanks for your effords!

Comment: If you marshal out an instance of your object what does the resulting XML look like for comparison to what your I put is?

Comment: It looks like: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><get_customer_request xmlns="http://example.org/tip/pro"/>

Comment: You get that if you marshal a fully populated object model?

Comment: Uhm, yes. This is the complete output I took from my server log.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: Something in your question tells me, that the output of my fully qualified object model should be significantly different. What would be the expected output? I can't see something too strange, except than the missing (since null) customer element.

Comment: I was curious what the output looked like if you populated everything (no null values). Then I could compare the input and output documents to infer what may be wrong in your mappings.

Comment: But I'm right with my opinion, that the output is a valid document according to my XSD, aren't I? So, where should I continue my research? For the (x-)files: This service was running for months, with one simple difference: I did not have nested elements - and I changed the namespaces due to a change in company name.

Comment: I'm just curious if there is any namespace qualification on the customer element if you marshalled it.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then I should just add some randomly self-generated customer element and do the marshalling. That's a helpful hint. Thanks. I will come back with hopefully better input tomorrow.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: When I create a new Id and set customerId.customer with this, the full output is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><get_customer_request xmlns="http://example.com/tip/pro"><customer name="xy" id="1"/></get_customer_request> - seems to look alright to me.

Comment: In your output the `customer` element is in the `example.com/tip/pro` namespace.  This means in your request it should have the `m` prefix.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: When putting m: prefix to customer element in my request, the parser complains that he found m:customer and expected customer. So far, I think it should be right without the m: but I am confused about this, because it all should be in the same namespace, and mentioning it explicitly should work, too, shouldn't it?

Comment: I have added an answer that should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12731274/383861

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PART 1**

> When I create a new Id and set customerId.customer with this, the full
>   output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<get_customer_request xmlns="example.com/tip/pro">
    <customer name="xy" id="1"/>
</get_customer_request>
```

Based on this information it appears that your JAXB mappings expect the `customer` element to be in the `example.com/tip/pro` namespace, and your request document should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<m:get_customer_request xmlns:m="http://example.org/tip/pro">
  <m:customer id="0" name="help"/>
</m:get_customer_request>
```

---

**PART 2**

> When putting m: prefix to customer element in my request, the parser
>   complains that he found m:customer and expected customer.

This means that your XML schema does not match your mappings.  If you expect the `customer` element to be in the namespace you can change your XML schema to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns:tip="http://example.org/tip" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://example.org/tip/pro"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    ...

</schema>
```

For more information on JAXB and namespaces see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer, and the useful link. I will try this and come back to mark your answer as a solution, I'm kind of sure it will solve my problem.

Comment: I had a month full of other priorities for this customer, so this issue to to wait. But finally your answer directed me to the solution.